# Movie identification about time travel remote

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

It's a movie where the main character has some sort of remote to control the last few seconds that happened (or a few days, but definitely not months or years).

It might appear that it could be [*Click*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389860/) starring Adam Sandler, but that movie is more of a comedy whereas the movie I am looking for is an action movie. It's not *Next* with Nicolas Cage either.

I remember a scene at the back where he prevented a bank robbery.

I remember the last part where the main character had to go back more than a few seconds, but that was for some reason hard or impossible; but he did it anyway.

Comment: So normally, they could only do a few seconds at a time? Do you remember whether it was something like a single-button device? Did it look like a regular TV remote? What sort of action did the protagonist get up to?

Comment: Was it an actual remote? [Next with Nicolas Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_(2007_film)) the character has the ability to see a few seconds into the future and in the end uses that to determine something very far in the future.

Comment: A few seconds or a few days, im not sure. But definitely not years or months. I don't remember much it's been years since I've seen this movie. I remember a scene at the back where he prevented a back robbery.

Comment: And it was definitely not Next ;)

Comment: There also was a Parker Lewis episod with a magic remote control, but it was a comedy too. Without the remote control element, that could be Next with Nicholas Cage (it's not really going back in time, but presented this way).

Comment: could it be "Slipstream" (2005) with Sean Aston? He invents a time machine, a watch-like device if I remember, goes to rob a bank an gets caught up with real bank robbers. At the end events and circumstances allow him to go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179094/movie-identification-about-time-travel-remote#comment484122_179094), this certainly sounds like [*Slipstream*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381601/) (2005).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(2005_film)):

> Stuart Conway (Sean Astin) has developed **a hand-held, cellphone-like time travel device called 'Slipstream' that allows the user to travel back in time 10 minutes** by interfacing with a cellphone system regional antenna. At first, he uses the device primarily to try, albeit unsuccessfully, to arrange a date with a female bank clerk. [...]
>
> During the fight, Stuart had been shot in the chest by a stray bullet. Before he dies, **Stuart takes Sarah and himself back in time to before the bank robbery, and Sarah unsuccessfully tries to foil the heist**. Unfortunately, Briggs takes the Slipstream device as a souvenir. Stuart and Sarah realize it's only a matter of time before Briggs and his cronies discover the true potential of the device. [...]
>
> Near the end, as a passenger in the falling airplane, Stuart is able to reverse the entire sequence of events because, being airborne, **he has access to many cellphone relay systems and therefore is not restricted to the 10-minute limit.**

Here's the trailer, where you can notably see the bank robbery and the Slipstream device ([here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7OqK.jpg) in case the video gets taken down):

Comment: This is it!!! Thank you so much!